# Get element of table on press of ENTER

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

When I click on the particular element (ie the each row of my table) i get my object but i want that element on `enter`.The below code will make you more clear,

Here is my object

```
var test = [{"name": "Ravi","age": 15}, {"name": "Shaul","age": 25}];
```

Here is my HTML table

```
<table id="mymthelptable" ng-show="getTableValue" class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-hover add-lineheight table_scroll" arrow-selector>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="(key, value) in test[0]">
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in test  | filter: searchText" ng-dblclick="setElement(item);">
            <td ng-hide="columnToHide.indexOf(key) !== -1" ng-repeat="(key, value) in item">
                {{value}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my js
I have written one directive

```
app.directive('arrowSelector', ['$document', function($document) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            // This function fires on double click of each row element
            scope.setElement = function(element) {
                    console.log(element) // Here i get the particular object like {"name" : "Ravi","age" : 15} if i click on first row
                }
                // This function fires on press enter of each row element
            $document.bind('keydown', function(e) {
                if (e.which == 13) {
                    console.log(e) // Here i want the object {"name" : "Ravi","age" : 15} like the upper one  but i did not get that
                    alert("wait");
                }
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Does the keydown event fire ? Does e.which=13 fire ? Do ypo have console.log after ?

Comment: ya it fires but i dont get the object

Comment: Does above code `scope.setElement` is working?

Comment: Yes it is working

Comment: You can't get like that. Because `onlcick` you can target a specific element. By `onEnter` you don't have a target element

Comment: Yes ,can i get that is there any other way

Comment: We can get only if it is a known element. Otherwise, we can't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ng-keydown instead of a directive and use the tab-index to give focus to the element you want to click enter on,below is a working snippet

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <table id="mymthelptable" class="" style="border: 1px solid black"
  ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th ng-repeat="(key, value) in test[0]"></th>
   </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
   <tr ng-repeat="item in test  | filter: searchText"
    ng-dblclick="setElement(item);">
    <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in item"
     ng-keydown="onkeydown(item,$event)" tabindex="0">{{value}}</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
 <script>
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

  app.controller('MyCtrl', [ '$scope', function($scope) {
   $scope.test = [ {
    "name" : "Ravi",
    "age" : 15
   }, {
    "name" : "Shaul",
    "age" : 25
   } ];
   $scope.setElement = function(element) {
    console.log(element)
   }
   $scope.onkeydown = function(item, $event) {
    console.log("get item " + item.name);
    console.log("get which" + $event.which)
    if ($event.which == 13) {
     alert("wait");
    }

   }
  } ]);
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow what does tabindex does

Comment: its giving me TypeError: ngModelCtrl is null

Comment: Usually tab index will be the number of tabs you would have to press to get to that element,but in this case the tab index is set to 0 to give focus to every td